# Empty query result on running django app on heroku, but normal results on development server

Tags: django, heroku

I just started using heroku today. I was testing a web application, and got different results on using django app from local development server and heroku. I had imported to the database by running the django development webserver. Since the postgredb uses the amazonaws url, I assumed that this data would be available to the production server on heroku.

From my local django webserver, the following search yields correct results:

```
from django.db.models import CharField
from django.db.models.functions import Lower
CharField.register_lookup(Lower, "lower")
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('testlogger')
logger.info('This is a simple log message')
items_set = []
if request.method == 'POST':
    print(request.POST.get)
    form = CGHSMetaForm(request.POST)
    name = request.POST.get('name').lower()
    items_set = CGHSRates.objects.filter(
        name__lower__contains=name).order_by('name')
    print(items_set)
    logger.info(items_set)
else:
    form = CGHSMetaForm()

return render(
    request, 'app/cghs_search.html', {
        'rnd_num': randomnumber(),       
        'form': form,
        'items': items_set,
    })
```

I get the following results:

```
Code
Name
Rate
1098
After Mastectomy (Reconstruction)Mammoplasty
Rs 13800.0
364
Local mastectomy-simple
Rs 14548.0
251
Mastoidectomy
Rs 17193.0
```

On heroku, however, I receive an empty result.

The database is the default heroku database, a postgre db, defined by the following settings in settings.py:

```
import dj_database_url
DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://kpnbcpyqtxxjqu:2c86exffsdff0d789e7f3b29d70sfsfsffs7be197sffsfsffb233@ec2-53-22-46-10.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dful1l3ra7nknn')}
```

Why does the same database when accessed on different servers yield different results? What should I be checking?

Answer (score 1):

But it's not using the same database. You've used `dj_database_url` and set the *default* to the AWS db; but there is probably an actual database configured in your Heroku settings, so the database environment variables will be populated and therefore that db will be used instead of the default.

If you want to hard-code your DB, you should do that directly in the settings, and not use dj_database_url at all.

Comment: That was it. I ended up ending the default database, and it worked. Can you give me an example of hard coding with this type of url?